# Help, did I just install without meaning to do so?

Tags: uninstall, update-manager

I was just trying out Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't want to install it just yet, but I clicked on software update and it began a long process. Is it actually installing? How do I stop or reverse that? I don't want it installing at all. I had not yet prepared the drive in which I wanted it installed, and I'm afraid it will install it in my Windows system drive.

Comment: The Terminal window keeps preparing, unpacking, and installing stuff. It's taking forever and I can't believe that is all happening on my boot flash drive. There's a button that says cancel, but I can't cancel anything. Where in the world is it installing all that stuff? Is this reversible? Will it destroy my Windows System installation? Please help!

Comment: If you are in the Live environment and have **not** executed the "Install Ubuntu 18.04.3" option from the Live, it's installing to RAM or persistence if you have it set up.

Comment: As long as you are still in the "Try Ubuntu" environment it won't affect your hard drive unless you did some complex things via command line - which seems unlikely.  The update process may fail if your USB runs out of room. If you didn't answer a bunch of questions about your user name, where you are located, etc, you are not installing.

Comment: Thanks, that's a relief; but it's been going on for over an hour. I've got 32G of RAM so maybe that's where it's going, but then it will all be gone when I shut down, so why does it even do that? Yeah, I made a mistake. Do Not do a software update in that situation. Might be nice if they advised you. It's been a long waste of time (un-cancellable). Will it do any damage if I just force quit? BTW, what is "persistence?"

Comment: Have a feeling that you downloaded 18.04 some time ago, and that it is trying to update to 18.04.03, that would be why it is taking a long time.  It is doing it because you told it to.  It will be updated if you decide to install before next booting.

Comment: It's a 16G flash drive. I remember allocating something like 4G for changes, so maybe I set up that "persistent" thing? I just checked and my Windows system drive is OK and intact. I booted from the flash drive again now, and checked that software updater again just to check if the update or any part of it stayed. When you're trying it out, is it in sudo mode? I wasn't asked for any password when I tried a sudo command. I just now downloaded it and it is 18.04.3 LTS. The machine is an Intel i5 with 32G of RAM and I've never seen an Ubuntu installation run as slow as this before.